# How do we solve N-Rooks variation using primes?

Tags: matrix, algorithm, puzzle

Using a $p_n $x $p_n$ matrix, how can we solve the [N-Rooks problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_polynomial) to find a prime in every row and column?

```
Table[MatrixForm[Table[If[PrimeQ[n], "P", "."], {m, 0, Prime[o]^2 - Prime[o], 
Prime[o]}, {n, m + 1, m + Prime[o]}]], {o, 1, 8}]
```

Here is the $11 $x$11$ matrix with the possible prime positions for the queens:

[image: N-RooksPrimeVariation]

Note: single primes are always in the $p$-th column.

This is one possible solution (done by hand):

[image: N-RooksPrimeSolution]

**Edit** Changed the title and link as Paxinum suggested.
[OEIS A215637](http://oeis.org/A215637) has these counts of multiple solutions through $10th$ prime:
$$ 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 72, 2144, 2641, 1345721, 2191254096$$

Comment: I think you need to qualify the question a bit more...  What is the equivalent condition of "two queens not attacking each other"?

Comment: @rm-rf, primes share no rows or colummns

Comment: Ah, I see. So your 11x11 was the set of all possible positions then...

Comment: @rm-rf, yes, All we need to do is circle one prime in each row and each column.  In this example, we would have 11 circles.

Comment: Then this is not an $n$-queen problem, but an $n$-rook problem...

Comment: @Paxinum, yes that is almost it.  Unlike either problem, we can't move the pieces around.  We must use what is available and remove what we don't need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very simple one, not very elegant :

```
f[o_] := Module[{mat, sol, vars, const, output}, 
  mat = Table[If[PrimeQ[n], Unique["p"], 0], {m, 0, Prime[o]^2 - Prime[o], 
    Prime[o]}, {n, m + 1, m + Prime[o]}];
  vars = Cases[Flatten[mat], _?(Not[NumericQ[#]] &)] ;
  const = Join[{Last[First[mat]] == 1}, Total[#] == 1 & /@ mat, 
    Total[#] == 1 & /@ Transpose[mat], 
    Thread[GreaterEqual[vars, 0]]];
  sol = FindInstance[const, vars, Integers];
  output = (mat /. First[sol])
]

f[8]/.{0 -> "."} //MatrixForm
```

[image: prime]

Comment: Hey, could you help me understand the puzzle?

Comment: I understood you want to build a matrix with "P"'s and 0's such that there is only one "P" in every row and column - some sort of simplified sudoku.

Comment: But couldn't those be 1s and 0s? What's prime about this?

Comment: The position where the 1's can be placed.

Comment: Oh so in 9x9 matrix, 2nd row, 1st column would be 10th position so you can't put a 1 there? Sorry, 5:50AM, slept 2hs yesterday

Comment: The dimension of the matrix is `Prime[o]`, so it can never be 9x9.

Comment: +1, very nice!  I was playing around with patterns of primes and thought a sudoku type of puzzle might be possible.  It seems to be computer solvable.  The last row of each matrix is one of the segements from Oppermann's Conjecture $(p^2-p,p^2]$

Answer (score 13):

Another possibility, at least for relatively small matrices, is to take the [determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) (strictly speaking it is the [permanent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent) that is required, I suppose).

For example, for an $11 \times 11$ matrix (`o=5`), I find there are 7 solutions.

```
primePositions5 = 
  Position[With[{o = 5}, 
    Table[If[PrimeQ[n], 1, 0], {m, 0, Prime[o]^2 - Prime[o], 
      Prime[o]}, {n, m + 1, m + Prime[o]}]], 1];

mylist = List @@ (Det@
     SparseArray[## -> Subscript[a, ##] & /@ 
       primePositions5] /. {-x_ -> x})
```

gives the following:

[image]

Matrix plots of all seven solutions:

```
MatrixPlot[
   Normal@SparseArray[(List @@ #) /. 
      Subscript[a, {x_, y_}] -> {x, y} -> 1], Mesh -> All, 
   ImageSize -> 200] & /@ mylist
```

I'll give then as a grid:

[image]

I reckon it needs to be emphasized that the *Mathematica*'s `Det` command is slow.

With `o=7` which gives a $17 \times 17$ matrix, I obtain 2144 solutions.  For `0 =8` ($19 \times 19$), the figure is 2641. I could not go beyond this with the computer I am using (with *Mathematica* 7, as it so happens).

For `o=4` ($7 \times 7$), I get two solutions:

[image: 7x 7 matrix]

#### Update for *Mathematica* 11

In Mma 11, we can use the [Permanent](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permanent.html) function

```
myListAlt = List @@ (SparseArray[## -> Subscript[a, ##] & /@  primePositions5] // 
 Permanent // Expand)
```

The behaviour of [Det](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Det.html) seems to have changed somewhat since this question was posted.
I now need to Expand the result of the Det function:

```
mylist = List @@ (Expand@
 Det@SparseArray[## -> Subscript[a, ##] & /@ 
    primePositions5] /. {-x_ -> x})
```

and

```
mylist == myListAlt
```

> True

Comment: Very nice solution! +1

Comment: FWIW: it is well-known that computing the permanent is an even more difficult task than computing the determinant...

Comment: The built-in `Permanent[]` can be a bit slow; see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38177) for slightly faster routines. I should also note at this point that Ilan Vardi discussed a similar problem in his book *Computational Recreations in Mathematica*.

Answer (score 5):

This is neither elegant nor smart nor memory efficient. It is a brute force method to get all solutions of a given size

```
isGood[m_] := Sort@m === reye@Length@m;
i : reye[l_] := i = Reverse@IdentityMatrix@l;

getAllSolutions[n_?PrimeQ] := With[{id = IdentityMatrix@n},
     Pick[id, #, 1] & /@ Boole@PrimeQ@Partition[Range[n^2], n] // 
     Tuples]~Select~isGood;
```

So

```
Row[MatrixForm /@ #] & /@ 
  Composition[getAllSolutions, Prime]~Array~4 // 
 Column@Riffle[#, "New prime"] &
```

Gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**EDIT**

I imagined that a solution along the lines of @bgatessucks 's great answer, but with booleans, would be more efficient and appropriate. However, while this is true for sizes below 13 (an order of magnitude faster in my tests), for some reason it suddenly becomes terribly slow afterwards.

```
v2[n_?PrimeQ, nsols_Integer: 1] := Module[{mat, vars},
  {mat, {vars}} = 
   Reap[PrimeQ@Partition[Range[n^2], n] /. True :> Sow@Unique["p"]];
  SatisfiabilityInstances[
    And @@ BooleanCountingFunction[{1}, n] @@@ 
      Join[mat, Transpose@mat], vars, nsols] /. 
   res_ :> (mat /. (Thread[vars -> #] & /@ res) /. {False -> ".", 
       True -> "P"})
  ]
```

Now

```
MatrixForm /@ v2[Prime@6, 3]
```

Gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @FredDanielKline, added an edit