# How do I find and enumerate the number of perfect matchings in directed complete graphs?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I would like to enumerate All the 1-factors or perfect matchings, of the complete directed graph Kn (the number of vertexes is even ) if there is an algorithm or method to enumerate all the perfect matchings?

Comment: Welcome to _Mathematica_.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with _Mathematica_ software.

Comment: Have you see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111576/how-to-get-the-perfect-matching-or-near-perfect-matching)?