# How to adjust a image as the empty image

Tags: image-processing, neural-networks

As [Vitaliy Kaurov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/13/vitaliy-kaurov)'s [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153695/21532) mentioned, anyone can use a method based on **Neural Network** (NN) to give a try? Then the bounty is deserved.

---

Suppose I have a empty paper like

[image]

Then I write some text on the paper,then the result paper have been distorted,rotated and translated.like

[image]

How to adjust the result papper **according the original empty paper**? As you see,some **empty transverse line can align [this two images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cwLg.png)**. The result like following is expected.

[image]

Actually I think the `ImageAlign` can help me(it cannot align a distorted image as its documentation).

```
ImageAlign[template, img, TransformationClass -> "Similarity"]
```

But it is a very slow and give me a poor result.Can anybody give a better solution for this?

Comment: Can you post images with clear external borders - this could help significantly.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov But it don't have a **clear** external borders...The post have all information I have.

Comment: ImageAlign works with the following transformations (as per the help): Translation, Rigid, Similarity, Affine, Perspective. The transformation of your paper looks to be nonlinear and/or spatially varying, so it is unlikely to work.

Comment: @bills Yes,I have read that before I post this question.

Comment: "The result like following is expected." --- how did you get that result?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov By Photoshop

Comment: @bills gives you the important hint. To register these two images onto each other perfectly, you will need a non-linear image registration algorithm. This is afaik currently not supported by Mathematica.

Comment: @halirutan of course you are right, but as `ImageMultiply[template, 
 ImageAlign[template, img, TransformationClass -> "Perspective"]]` may demonstrate, even an unrestricted linear transform works not too bad for the given example, and also is not really slow.

Comment: @UDB Why you think that is [not bad](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UInzq.png)?

Comment: @yode try `ImageMultiply[#1, ImageAlign[#1, #2, TransformationClass -> "Perspective"]] &[Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/euyxY.jpg", Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/fymre.jpg"]` and tell us what you see.

Comment: You should get [Taliesin Beynon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7140/taliesin-beynon) in here to give you a hand (or xslittlegrass). Or google [WSS17] "NetTrain" or look at the stuff on community. Lots of people working with neural nets there.

Comment: @Taliesin Beynon Bounties wait you here. (also @xslittlegrass)

Answer (score 7):

I will give just a start, which I think is not bad already. First just for faster computing times I resize your images:

```
i1 = ImageResize[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/nerv4.jpg"], 400];
i2 = ImageResize[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/czNNK.jpg"], 400];
```

Next `FindGeometricTransform`

```
{e, t} = FindGeometricTransform[i1, i2]
```

[image]

Then you can go both ways which give you same result, but 1st is faster:

```
ImagePerspectiveTransformation[i2, t, DataRange -> Full]
```

or

```
ImageForwardTransformation[i2, t, DataRange -> Full]
```

[image]

The same result could be obtained as

```
pts = ImageCorrespondingPoints[i1, i2];
{cpe, cpt} = FindGeometricTransform @@ pts
ImagePerspectiveTransformation[i2, t, DataRange -> Full]
```

You can try playing with `ImageFeatureTrack`, `ImageLines`, and some manual manipulation of extracted features, for example manual specification or editing points/lines after `ImageCorrespondingPoints`/`ImageLines` before they go into `FindGeometricTransform`. You could also try training a [Neural Network](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NeuralNetworks.html) (NN) on a bunch if similar simulated transformations. Advantage of NN is it could potentially be very fast.

Comment: As I know,those matrix just can process linear transformation..

Comment: @yode, why do you believe the distortion in your images cannot be approximated by a linear fractional transformation?

Comment: @J.M. I just juess,I think that cannot be solved by a matrix transformation.I think we need a new solution. And I think [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/112221/21532) is a good start.

Comment: I'm confused still.If we use a NN method. How to get those trianning image. I mean if I just trainnig the image posted in the question with different transform. Then we can deal with other image with different transform?

Comment: @yode you have to generate set of random images where you do know the transform.

Comment: @yode actually, a correction, you have to generate set of random images where you start from wanted result (normal image, output of NN) and deform it somehow (input of NN).

Comment: I don't very familar thos NN thing..I have to give you still.

Comment: I note after I update the image, your method don't work anymore or I have missed some thing?